# How to turn off indexing in my Java Servlet Application

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

While "index.html" file is situated at the root of my web app, the request on the root path automatically gets back that "index.html" file, even if there's some mapping for root path requests.

Help me pls to turn off automatical serving of index file in TomCat.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `<welcome-file-list>` in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml` or in `web.xml` of your web application.

More details you can find here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=103099265#content/view/103099265